# why css not applied on preview mode network tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using `nextjs` for server side.I am facing a issue that my `css class` is not applied on `preview tab` it only applied on client why .? here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-jackson-lqmiy?file=/pages/index.js
[image]

how to apply css on preview mode as all server side application see page on preview tab.

```
export default function IndexPage() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      </Head>

      <a className="red">About</a>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @juliomalves if you see any big company https://www.oracle.com/customers/ or https://www.google.com/ style is applied

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. That's because their styles are part of the HTML document, and not in a separate CSS file that requires to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Links included in `<head></head>` are processed in the following way:

1. Browser fetches the server response.
2. Browser sees CSS link in the HTML head.
3. Browser fetches the CSS file, reads and applies it.

If you want to include CSS to the page straight away, well, you need to add CSS code to the page itself. There are many ways to do it with built-in CSS support in Next.js (see [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support)).